# how to pass html DOM element to onclick javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom, onclick

I have a table with multiple rows. For each row I need to pass a php value $myvalue to a java script function myJSfunction inside onclick as below. I tried to pass it via a javascript variable (engenes[thiskey]), but it only keeps and pass the value from last row, thus the last value when click on the page. It looks like the javascript variable can not stored until it is clicked. Now I am trying to pass the value from the table via DOM element since the value is there when clicked as follows. but somehow the value of the DOM element can not be passed onto myJSfunction as input value for list and description. thanks.

php variable $myvalue and javascript variable thiskey were defined.

```
    <table  border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="1" class="tablehead">

    <?php foreach ($hg2sl as $key => $myvalue) { ?>  
    <tr>
      <td class="rowB" align="center" valign="top"><p id="mystr"><?php echo $myvalue; ?></p></td>

       <td class="rowB" align="center" valign="top"><a onclick="enrich({list: document.getElementById('str4enrich').innerHTML, popup: true, description: document.getElementById('str4enrich').innerHTML });"><script type="text/javascript">document.write(thiskey)</script></a></td>

    </tr>
    <?php }; ?>

Below is the javascript function

function myJSfunction(options) {
if (typeof options.list === 'undefined') {
    alert('No genes defined.');
}

var description  = options.description || "",
    popup = options.popup || false,
    form = document.createElement('form'),
    listField = document.createElement('input'),
    descField = document.createElement('input');

form.setAttribute('method', 'post');
form.setAttribute('action', 'http://amp.pharm.mssm.edu/Enrichr/enrich');
if (popup) {
    form.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
}
form.setAttribute('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');

listField.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
listField.setAttribute('name', 'list');
listField.setAttribute('value', options.list);
form.appendChild(listField);

descField.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
descField.setAttribute('name', 'description');
descField.setAttribute('value', description);
form.appendChild(descField);

document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
document.body.removeChild(form);
}
```

Comment: 1. Ids have to be _unique_; 2. Please add a [mcve] that shows the actual problem.

Comment: `document.getElementById('mystr').value` ... *mystr* doesn't have a value, it's a `<p>` tag; try `document.getElementById('mystr').innerHTML` instead.

Comment: Thanks, Andreas. Please see the added code. and which ids are you referring to?

Comment: Basically I'm trying to link to enrichr from each row and use the information in the same row as the input list. I've changed to innerHTML. but the value passed to myJSfunction for all the rows are the same, the value for the first row now.